# Where can I see current usage data for Google Cloud Speech To Text?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

### I need to know how many **minute** I have used.

I can't find it anywhere in the dashboard.

(By the way, Google Speech to Text API have 60 minute/month free trial)

[image]
[image]

### Update: @mk_sta's answer seem like correct:

[image]

But after more testing,
(upload a 55 seconds audio and check if 393+55=448)

It doesn't work. the number still is 393（"7 Day Peak Usage") 
[image]

But "Current Usage" did change to 55.
which is correct,
but the left showed "Audio second per day",
I don't need "per day"

### I need "Current Month Total Audio Second"

Comment: This is such a shame so basic a function is seemingly missing from the console

Answer (score 0):

Although GCP [Cloud Speech-to-Text](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech) service diffuses specific [Content](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas#content) limits for audio data sources leveraging [Quotas & limits](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas) approach,  I guess you can find this [billing](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/pricing) related characteristic in GCP [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/quotas?project=_&_ga=2.207423763.1848489890.1586147462-1591645931.1562589647&_gac=1.49465106.1586504771.EAIaIQobChMIuLnF2q3d6AIVFaqaCh3SywpzEAAYASAAEgLouvD_BwE) page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping, but this is "7 Day Peak Usage", not "Total Usage" or "Current Month Usage"

Comment: Yeah, it keeps 7 days retention, moreover I've found no suitable metric that can reflect audio duration, however you can raise a feature request to the particular developer group within Google public issue [tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list).